# Oracle 12c: Gather Statistics only for New Partitions

Tags: oracle, partitioning

I recently converted several large tables in Oracle 12c to using daily interval range partitioning on a date field and partitioned indexes. As part of the data load process, i execute the gather stats procedure on the table at the end after the data has been inserted and committed. Interval partitioning makes it easier as new partitions are automatically created when new data inserted does not belong in any of the existing partitions' upper limits. However, I noticed that the time it takes to execute the gather stats procedure is significant, taking many hours for tables that have a row count in the hundred millions. The thing is: majority of the data does not change so I am only interested in gathering stats for the partitions which are new or where the data has changed. Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: You simple can copy statistics into new partition form previous full partition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly what [incremental statistics](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_stats.htm#GUID-7BECE839-ACC5-4768-8BE6-A16AAD14A9ED) was built for.

With incremental statistics, Oracle will only gather partition statistics for partitions that have changed.  Synopses are built for each partition, and those synopses are quickly combined to create global statistics without having to re-scan the whole table.

To enable it you only need to set a table preference and then gather statistics.  The first gather will be slow but future statistics gathering will be much faster.

```
begin
    dbms_stats.set_table_prefs('TABLE_OWNER', 'TABLE_NAME', 'incremental', 'true');
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('TABLE_OWNER', 'TABLE_NAME');
end;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go. Script for gathering statistic by partition value. Maybe it helps you:

```
declare
  v_table_name varchar2(64) := ''; --your table
  v_key_value number := ;  -- your range value

  v_data_object_id number;
  v_object_name varchar2(64);
  v_object_type varchar2(64);
  v_granularity varchar2(64);
  v_part_name   varchar2(64);
begin
  begin
    for i in (select kc.column_name
              from user_part_key_columns kc
              where kc.name = upper(v_table_name)
                and kc.object_type = 'TABLE')
     loop
       execute immediate 'select /*+ first_rows */ dbms_rowid.rowid_object(rowid)

                          from ' || v_table_name || '
                          where '|| i.column_name || ' = '|| v_key_value || 
                          ' and rownum = 1'
        into v_data_object_id;
     end loop;
  exception
    when no_data_found then
      v_data_object_id := null;
  end;

  begin
    select t.subobject_name, t.OBJECT_TYPE
      into v_object_name, v_object_type
    from user_objects t
    where t.data_object_id = v_data_object_id;
    exception
      when no_data_found then
        v_object_name := null;
  end;

  if v_object_name is null
    then
      dbms_output.put_line ('no data found');
    else
      if v_object_type = 'TABLE SUBPARTITION'
        then 
          v_granularity := 'SUBPARTITION';

          select t.partition_name
            into v_part_name
          from user_tab_subpartitions t
          where t.subpartition_name = v_object_name;

        else
          v_granularity := 'PARTITION';
          v_part_name := v_object_name;
      end if;

      dbms_stats.gather_table_stats (ownname => user
                                    ,tabname => upper(v_table_name)
                                    ,partname => v_part_name
                                    ,granularity => v_granularity
                                    ,cascade => true
                                    ,no_invalidate => false);
  end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution would be this one:

```
BEGIN
FOR aPart IN (SELECT TABLE_NAME, PARTITION_NAME FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YOUR_TABLE' AND LAST_ANALYZED IS NULL) LOOP
    DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(USER, aPart.TABLE_NAME, aPart.PARTITION_NAME);
END LOOP;
END;
```